# lc-3: Loading a number into a register and Outputting it in the form of binary

Tags: coding-style, computer-science, lc3

I need help inputing a number into the console of an LC-3 simulator, such as 1 2 9,
grab the number 129 and actually form it into the full number 129, (one hundred and twenty nine) and the output its binary form to the screen of the console.

How do I do this?
Any help would be great.